# Position 3D cursor in X without changing to object's Y coordinate

Tags: 3d-cursor

I'm trying to position the 3D cursor to a specific coordinate inside an object (not the center). when I move the cursor to where I want it in the X plane, it moves the Y coordinate to the surface of the object.

How can I get the 3D cursor to ignore the shape of the object, and let me place it in the coordinates I'm setting in one or more planes.

Comment: You can select any face, edge, or vertex and press Shift+S and select "Cursor to selected" to place the 3D cursor anywhere you want. Selecting 2 (or more) points will place the cursor in the center of the selected points.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "place in the coordinates in one or more planes". If you already have an object placed there, you can snap the cursor to it by _Shift+S_ > _Cursor to Selected_. In _Object Mode_ this refers to the object's origin, in _Edit Mode_ to the center of one or more selected vertices, edges pr faces. If you want to place the 3D cursor to distinct coordinates you can't snap to you also have the option to press _N_ on the keyboard and bring up the side menu in the viewport. Under the _View_ tab you can enter X, Y, Z values for the cursor and also change the rotation.

Comment: You can use the ortho perspective keys (numpad 1,3,7,9) to constrain your view to just 2 axes in any particular direction, and then move the cursor with `Shift + Right-Click`. It will move in the 2 axes you can see, but will not change "depth" in that perspective, if that makes any sense (ex: from the "front" (numpad1), it will move in X and Z, but not Y). You might have to switch views and repeat a couple of times, but you'll have full control over where the cursor goes.

Comment: im hoping to avoid snapping or using an object so I can position the cursor with my mouse in places where no topolagy exists

Answer (score 0):

- Goto *View* tab
- Expand *3D Cursor* section
- Change the *Location* coordinates

[image]

To snap object to the 3D cursor, click <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> or press <kbd>**W**</kbd>.

[image: Snap]

Comment: thank you for the suggestiom, but Im after an non setting ai to speak where the cursor behaves like nothing is there so I can position it with my mouse